# Show that any power function with an equation of the form $y = a^x$, where $a > 0$, has the property that for all values of $b$, $f(x+b) = f(x)f(b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that any power function with an equation of the form $y = a^x$, where $a > 0$, has the property that for all values of $b$, $f(x+b) = f(x)f(b)$.
Interpret his property in terms of transformations.
How would one go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \forall (x,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2, \ f(x+b)= a^{x+b}=a^x a^b=f(x)f(b)$$

I dont really know what you mean by transformation.

I can tell you that $f$ is an isomorphism between the groups $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_+^*,\times)$